# MySql: select data based on timestamp and dynamic interval

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, php-carbon

In my MySql DB I have these fields:

```
 id | email_id |  interval  |      start_at       |    last_sent_at
--- | -------- | ---------- | ------------------- | -------------------
 1  |   8293   | +6 months  | 2017-06-14 16:59:54 | 2017-06-14 16:59:54
--- | -------- | ---------- | ------------------- | -------------------
 2  |   8904   |   (NULL)   | 2017-05-14 12:32:45 |      (NULL)
```

I am trying to create a dynamic way for users to set a schedule for an email job in laravel. The idea is to use laravel's commands scheduler to run a command that checks all scheduled emails and then runs them if they haven't been sent (whereNull(last_sent_at)) or if the last time they were sent was more than the current time minus 6 months or 12 months or what ever they select for that field.

I have tried several different queries to get this to work to no avail. In laravelized code I have tried the following...

```
$schedules = Schedule::selectRaw('schedules.schedulable_id, schedules.schedulable_type, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(schedules.interval) as NowPlusInterval')
    ->whereNull('last_sent_at')
    ->orWhere('schedules.last_sent_at', '>=', 'NowPlusInterval')
    ->get();
```

and

```
$schedules = Schedule::whereNull('last_sent_at')
    ->orWhereRaw('schedules.last_sent_at >= NOW()-'.Carbon::parse('schedules.interval')->toDateTimeString())
    ->get();
```

and many many other variations. The second one is the simplest to me *but* because I am passing the db field to a php function it doesn't recognize that I am trying to get the value from the db field (not parse a string called 'schedules.interval'). Is there anyway write this field into a variable that Carbon can parse or is there a raw mysql query that I can run that will **give me all the fields where last_sent_at is null and where now minus the interval listed is more than the last_sent_at.**

I've racked my brain on this for hours. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql's DATE_SUB() and INTERVAL functions. Something to the effect of:

```
->whereRaw('last_sent_at >= SUB_DATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)')
```

or perhaps this:

```
->whereNull('last_sent_at')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw('DATE(`schedules.last_sent_at`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `schedules.interval`')))
    ->get();
```

Comment: I've done this too, the problem is I cannot figure out how to pass my DB feild into the INTERVAL portion of the SUB_DATE() function. If you can show me how to pass in 'schedules.interval' where it says 6 MONTH the answer is yours! ie: ->whereRaw('schedules.last_sent_at >= SUB_DATE(NOW(), INTERVAL schedules.interval)') ... and yes, this was one of my many attempts and it just tries to read schedules.interval as a string instead of the db value.

Comment: I really appreciate the idea. I tried it (minus the extra parenthesis at the end) and got this... `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `schedules` where `last_sent_at` is null or DATE(`schedules.last_sent_at`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `schedules.interval` is null)` any other ideas?

Comment: I can change my db structure if needed... anyone have any ideas?